# Get date format in Python in Windows

Tags: python, locale, date-format, localeconv

In a sample code given to me for my homework, this line appears:

```
date_format = locale.nl_langinfo(locale.D_FMT)
```

But in Windows that line returns the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\Shadark\Dropbox\IHM\P3\p3_files\www\cgi-bin\todolist.py", line 11, in <module>
date_format = locale.nl_langinfo(locale.D_FMT)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'nl_langinfo'
```

I've read about using **localeconv** but I only read about it being used currency or numbers. Any idea on uses for the purpose of my code sample or other kind of function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is probably the fact that `locale.nl_langinfo` doesn't appear to be available in Windows Python 2.7.x (I don't see it in my copy of Windows 64-bit Python 2.7.3).  Looking at the docs at http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/locale.html#locale.nl_langinfo, they specifically say:

> This function is not available on all systems, and the set of possible options might also vary across platforms.

Once you've set the locale up with something along the lines of:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'english')
```

Then calls to some_date.strftime() will use correct locale specific formatting and strings.  So if you want the date in string format, call `some_date.strftime('%x')` replace the `%x` with `%X` for time or `%c` for both.  The full list of strftime formats are documented [here](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

```
>>> d = datetime.datetime.now()
... for loc in ('english', 'german', 'french'):
...     locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, loc)
...     print loc, d.strftime('%c -- %x -- %X -- %B -- %A')
english 11/15/2012 4:10:56 PM -- 11/15/2012 -- 4:10:56 PM -- November -- Thursday
german 15.11.2012 16:10:56 -- 15.11.2012 -- 16:10:56 -- November -- Donnerstag
french 15/11/2012 16:10:56 -- 15/11/2012 -- 16:10:56 -- novembre -- jeudi
14: 'French_France.1252'
```

Comment: And some workaround for getting date_format in Python in the same way nl_langinfo works, but without using it?

Comment: how do you get date/time/datetime format string on windows?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing any pre-compiled files from the test directory.

If the problem persists, try reinstalling your compile extension. Maybe there was a problem with the installation