# Get user date format in Windows

Tags: python, datetime, outlook, pywin32

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401587/get-date-format-in-python-in-windows), however, I don't want to get the date format of the `locale`, but the one set by the user. The reason is that I am using the `pywin32` api to communicate with Outlook, specifically to filter mails by date. The format in which I have to pass the date to the application is the one set by the user, otherwise it won't work.

So the code looks like this:

```py
inbox = outlook.Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(user, 6)

mails = inbox.Items.Restrict(
            "[ReceivedTime] > '{}'".format(retrieve_from.strftime(local_date_fmt))
)
```

If anyone knows how to do this without passing the date in the user defined format, that would also solve my problem.

**EDIT**:

I am referring to the short date format set in the region settings in this window:

[image: Region Settings window]

So in this case, `local_date_fmt` would be set to `%Y-%m-%d`.

Comment: "*but the one set by the user*". Set where? The user sets it via *Region Settings*. Also are you talking about long or short formats? Please be more specific, and also provide some examples.

Comment: Yes, via *Region Settings*. Short format. I will extend the question.

Comment: Could the person who downvoted this let me know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [[MS.Learn]: GetDateFormatW function (datetimeapi.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/datetimeapi/nf-datetimeapi-getdateformatw), which is wrapped by [[ME.TimGolden]: win32api.GetDateFormat](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32api__GetDateFormat_meth.html).

Example:

> ```py
> >>> import time
> >>> import pywintypes as pwts
> >>> import win32api as wapi
> >>>
> >>> DATE_SHORTDATE = 0x00000001
> >>> DATE_LONGDATE = 0x00000002
> >>>
> >>> cur_time = time.time()
> >>> cur_time
> 1567692860.7315922
> >>> time.ctime(cur_time)
> 'Thu Sep  5 17:14:20 2019'
> >>>
> >>> wapi.GetDateFormat(0, DATE_SHORTDATE, pwts.Time(cur_time))
> '2019-09-05'
> >>>
> >>> wapi.GetDateFormat(0, DATE_LONGDATE, pwts.Time(cur_time))  # Bonus
> 'Thursday, 5 September, 2019'
> ```